# 405 Method Not Allowed in implementing a custom HTTP method (possibly not a URL matching issue)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently playing with JAX-RS, using Jersey. I was following the instructions [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9780596809300/ch04.html) to try and implement a custom AUDIT method. I faced an issue where this AUDIT call was returning a "405 Method Not Allowed" message.

Below are the services that I have implemented so far.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("v1/Customers")
public Response createCustomers(final Customer input)

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("v1/Customers/{customerid: .*}")
public Response readCustomers(@PathParam("customerid") String customerId)

@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("v1/Customers/{customerid}")
public Response updateCustomers(@PathParam("customerid") String customerId, final Customer input)

@DELETE
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("v1/Customers/{customerid}")
public Response deleteAlerts(@PathParam("customerid") String customerId)

@AUDIT
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("v1/Customers/{customerid}")
public Response getCustomerHistory(@PathParam("customerid") String customerId)
```

Many of the responses to these kind of questions on SO indicate that there is a problem with the URL for the AUDIT call. However, when I replaced the `@Path` for the AUDIT call with, say, `v1/Customers/test/{customerid}` the call goes through perfectly. Besides URL issues, I cannot think of any other reason why the error occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How does the annotation for your custom method look like? Seems to me the problem is there.

Comment: Hi @MustSeeMelons, thank you for your comment. As I mentioned, I am following the instructions outlined [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9780596809300/ch04.html). So, my code looks as follows:

`@Target({ElementType.METHOD})`
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @HttpMethod("AUDIT")`
`@Documented`
`public @interface AUDIT { }`

Comment: For a good name convention in your REST API, move your v1 to your context path and Customer (in lower case) to the top of your class.